# Navigation View Layout Fragment Not Showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigationview

I'm trying to create Navigation View Fragment. I create this. It works. But it does not show proberly. I have 2 xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

And my second xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

[image]

If i use first code it gives an output in the picture of left side. if i use second code it gives an output in the picture of right side. How can i solve this problem ? Thank you so much.

[image]

fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.hp.myapplication.MainFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<Button
    android:text="Burası Ana Sayfa Fragmenti"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Comment: Can you post what is the expected result, and also full xml file would be helping ?

Comment: i want to create right side. but it's showing in the toolbar area ? isn't it ?

Comment: if i do left side it does not show like right side.

Comment: yes your framgent is probably under the Toolbar you can add a marginTop=?attr/actionBarSize and you should see it.

Comment: ok.i don't want this. i want under the toolbar and not toolbar special side.

Comment: I am not clear what do you mean by i want under the toolbar and not toolbar special side. Especially  "and not toolbar special side"

Comment: so you want your fragment to be centered vertically in the he layout ?

Comment: Can you show the layout.xml for the fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

Your framgent container is located under the toolbar and take full widht and full height of the screen.

To have the content of the fragment center vertically you can use

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   tools:context="com.example.hp.myapplication.MainFragment">

   <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

   <Button
    android:text="Burası Ana Sayfa Fragmenti"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</Framelayout>
```